# Can I change an icon to appear clickable on mouseover or hover - if the code was provided by an external site?

Tags: clickable-image

I have a Google Partner Badge on my site, based on code that Google provides.  They provide the code, and it creates a dynamic image on my site, that is clickable and a live link.  However, the cursor does not change to a hand when over the image or indicate it is a live link in any way.  In my opinion, this is bad UX. 
I want to simply make the cursor change to a hand when hovering over the image. 
But again, the original code is provided by an external site.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<span style="cursor:pointer">
// external code here
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

inspect elements then find the container of that image, then add style on it.

```
.containerOfGoogleBadge {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```